# How do I fix setuptools not available in build environment when trying to install libraries in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, pip, setuptools

I'm trying to install a requirements.txt file in Docker, and I make it about 30 packages in when I get this error when trying to install importlib:

Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.

Here is the full error message:

```
Collecting importlib==1.0.4
#9 14.42   Downloading importlib-1.0.4.zip (7.1 kB)
#9 14.43   Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
#9 14.45   Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
#9 14.45   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#9 14.45   
#9 14.45   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
#9 14.45   │ exit code: 1
#9 14.45   ╰─> [1 lines of output]
#9 14.45       ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
#9 14.45       [end of output]
#9 14.45   
#9 14.45   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#9 14.45 error: metadata-generation-failed
#9 14.45 
#9 14.45 × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
#9 14.45 ╰─> See above for output.
#9 14.45 
#9 14.45 note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
#9 14.45 hint: See above for details.
```

In the Dockerfile, I have tried installing setuptools before installing the packages:

```
RUN python3 -m pip install setuptools
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Some further details: my python version is 3.9, pip version is 22.1.2

When I do

```
easy_install --version
```

, I get

```
setuptools 41.0.1 from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python (Python 2.7)
```

However, when I try to install setuptools with pip, it says I have version 62.3.3 for python3.9

```
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages (62.3.3)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, and let me know if I should provide any further details.

Comment: Why is it trying to install `importlib`? `importlib` is part of Python's standard library, so it should always be available without needing to install it from _PyPI_ with _pip_. -- To be accurate there is an `importlib` on _PyPI_ but it is meant only for very old versions of Python that do not have `importlib` out of the box.

Comment: It means one of the dependencies only works on python2

Comment: I'm here because I just installed pandas and the Excel reader fails in importlib:
  File ~/DataScience/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/compat/_optional.py:141, in import_optional_dependency(name, extra, errors, min_version)
    140 try:
--> 141     module = importlib.import_module(name)
    142 except ImportError:
and when I try 'pip install importlib' THAT fails on setuptools.

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned in the comments, the error appears because you are trying to install `importlib` on Python 3.9, while it's meant for much older Python versions only.

Just remove `importlib` from your `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: you may right. I am also facing problem installing Python 3.9 version. Needs lot of effort to install library such as pygrib, cfgrib, eccodes, basemap-data-hires, etc. But it is good to upgrade the python version now as the developer is on its way for debugging..

Comment: sadly, imp is being removed in py 3.12, so I guess someone is going 'back' to importlib..